# Unable to query Task Queues on VF page load?

Tags: apex, soql, tasks, queue, spring-20

I have a bit of a frustrating problem. On my VF page, I am getting queues that are assigned to a selected Object. When a user selects 'Task' from the drop down of available objects from an `<apex:selectOptions>` component, an actionSupport method is fired that gets queues for the object selected (in this case, Task). The results look like this:

[image]

First line is selected object, second line is what the query is constructed as, third line are the results. This scratch org has two Queues assigned to Task.

Now, when a user comes back to this page, it needs to pre-load saved values, so it needs to gather Queues for the selected object (Task) in the constructor. The debug for that looks like this:

[image]

We still have Task as the selected object, query is exactly the same, but magically nothing returns... It even goes into the exact same method used by the action support on picklist value change.

The VF page and the controller both have apiVersion set to 48 in their meta.xml file. Why can I query Task queues from an actionSupport after page loads, but not on page load in the constructor?? Any other object works fine, the constructor can grab queues assigned to any other object. Tasks being allowed in Queues is new of Spring '20 and api 48, is this just a bug? Or did I miss some api version setting somewhere? Does anyone know what is going on here?